# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message with an embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am having issues with sending discord embeds. This is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'tiktok',
    description: "sends tiktok link",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#228B22')
        .setTitle('Tiktok')
        .setURL('https://www.tiktok.com/@elcattuccino?lang=en')
        .setDescription('tiktok link for the discord server')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Tiktok', value:'heres the tiktok link'},
        )
        .setImage('https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/752212130870329384/6a16609eafc28f95ad8f64e80ffcc24e.png?size=80')
        .setFooter('check out the tiktok');
        
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
> ^
>
> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\willm\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\willm\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord
> Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
> at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\willm\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15)
> {   method: 'post',   path: '/channels/910099863180550144/messages',
> code: 50006,   httpStatus: 400,   requestData: {
> json: {
> content: undefined,
> tts: false,
> nonce: undefined,
> embeds: undefined,
> components: undefined,
> username: undefined,
> avatar_url: undefined,
> allowed_mentions: undefined,
> flags: undefined,
> message_reference: undefined,
> attachments: undefined,
> sticker_ids: undefined
> },
> files: []   } }

Comment: Are you using v13 of discord.js?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using discord.js v13, you should send an embed like this as you can send up to 10 embeds now:

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] });
```

The embed option was removed and replaced with an embeds array, which must be in the options object. [More info](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#commonly-used-methods-that-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] });`

Also field has changed

`.addField('LINK', '[LINK](TIKTOK LINK)', true)`
like this

Comment: The `.addField` is fine