# Bot doesnt send embed in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So, I can't manage to make my bot send a message (embed) I am using discord.js 14. I dont even know what I did wrong. The code is straight from discord.js embed docs I have tried 3 days to solve the issue, but it somehow doesnt see the Embed. I dont know what I did wrong, I dont know what is wrong. But anyways I want to ask for help so here's the code =

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, messageLink, InteractionResponseType } = require('discord.js');
const logger = require('winston');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('aaaa');
const prefix = "pp!";
const token = "69420"
//text
bot.on('ready', () => { // when the bot is ready and online
    console.log('bot is now online!')
});


// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('SoARAtle')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

    bot.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
        if (message.content.includes('dn')) {
            message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        }
      
      });

    bot.login(token)  ```

This is the error it gives : Uncaught DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord APIerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987766/discord-apierror)

Comment: Since v13, the way to send an embed is by the `embeds` option: `.send({ embeds: [embed] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On discord.js v13+ and v14+ we don't send embeds like yours anymore. You need to assign embeds, components, attachments, and content separately to your message.

```js
message.channel.send({ content:'Hello World!', embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```